# Caret: PCA preprocessing and partitioning train and test data

Tags: pca, caret

My training and test data are in two distinct .csv files:

```
credit <- read.csv('/Users/dbl/Downloads/Loans Question/RequiredAttributesWithLoanStatusAdjusted.csv')

creditTesting <- read.csv('/Users/dbl/Downloads/Loans Question/NewLoansReducedFields.csv')

credit$LoanStatus <- as.factor(credit$LoanStatus)
```

I'm using Caret's preProcess=c("center", "scale", "pca") methods in the training phase.

```
logitBoostFit <- train(LoanStatus~., credit, method = "LogitBoost", family=binomial, preProcess=c("center", "scale", "pca"), 
    trControl = ctrl)
```

How is PCA applied to the test data in the predict phase?

```
logitBoostClasses <- predict(logitBoostFit, newdata = creditTesting)
```

If I concatenate both files into one and partition one file into
training and testing, so that the scaling, normalization, mapping of categorical to numerical is consistent don't I violate the principal of separating training from test data?

Comment: No, pre-processing the data doesn't it expose it to any procedure.  If one scales the training data, one needs to scale the test data too.

Comment: My comment assumes you don't throw out any of the components.  It does beg the question of why one would want to do this, since a choice of a basis is irrelevant  for prediction,

Comment: This is for credit scoring: the regulators need to see which factors led to your decision.  The requirement was to reduce the number of attributes from 44 to 7 (or whatever number of attributes can predict 95% of the variation in the data.)

Comment: How can I 'tease out' the (5-7) original attributes that the PCA pre-processing step selected as factors?

Comment: This sounds like a business project, so tread carefully with any free advice.  I would think that from a govt perspective you need to do PCA on the entire data set.  If your lucky, you can find 5-7 variables that account for enough variance or that the first 5-7 PCA factors account for 95% of the variance. Else just take enough factors to get your 95%.

Comment: Is each PCA factor a 'linear combination' of ALL the input attributes that the PCA analyzed, with weights corresponding to the magnitude of the dimension for that input attribute?  Are the weights eigen values?

Comment: Yes.  I have no idea if your regulators will accept that.  If they demand you create a model from 5-7 variables and they demand you start with 44 variables you may be in an impossible situation.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can have them in two different data sets. `train` will store the loadings created from the training set (and the means and standard deviations) and apply them to the new samples being predicted. In other words, the new samples are projected using the training set information without recomputing anything.

Max

Answer (score 1):

For caret you do not need to preproces the test data. That is included in the model. When you call on predict with new data, it will be preprocessed according to the preproces rules you specified with training the model.