# Can I perform cluster analysis before PCA?

Tags: clustering, pca

I would like to know what are pros and cons of performing cluster analysis before/after PCA?
My data are not very well explained by the first and the second PC (49%), so I am thinking it would be more beneficial to apply PCA after clustering just for visualization than to use PCA for feature extraction and perform cluster analysis afterward.

Please let me know if my thought process makes sense. I am relatively new to this field.

P.S. I have to only use these 2 tools for my analysis as part of a requirement.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172346/caret-pca-preprocessing-and-partitioning-train-and-test-data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would PCA help with a k-means clustering analysis?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157621/how-would-pca-help-with-a-k-means-clustering-analysis)

Comment: @utobi Thank you for the link. I am using a normal PCA. I am not sure if it is relevant to validating the clustering algorithm using Kernel PCA